# Sort array into dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, sorting, nsdictionary

I have and array of many strings.
I wan't to sort them into a dictionary, so all strings starting the same letter go into one array and then the array becomes the value for a key; the key would be the letter with which all the words in it's value's array begin.

Example

```
Key = "A" >> Value = "array = apple, animal, alphabet, abc ..."
Key = "B" >> Value = "array = bat, ball, banana ..."
```

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
NSArray *list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple, animal, bat, ball", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *word in list) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [[word substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
    NSMutableArray *letterList = [dict objectForKey:firstLetter];
    if (!letterList) {
        letterList = [NSMutableArray array];
        [dict setObject:letterList forKey:firstLetter];
    }
    [letterList addObject:word];
}
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

Comment: Note that you'll quite likely end up with many more than 26 arrays in `dict` in the face of UTF-8 input and non-English languages.  This code will still work, but there are a whole slew of intricate details when it comes to sorting non-English words.

Comment: Sure, we do have more than 26 letters in other parts of the world. ;) I don't really see why this would be a problem though. The question was not how to sort these (easy with `localizedCompare:` btw), but how to group them by first letter. There's nothing in the question about a requirement to end up with exactly 26 arrays.

Comment: Right -- which is why I gave you an upbeat.  Just pointing out that Ä, A, and Å are all going to end up in separate buckets which may or may not matter (and, of course, what is the uppercaseString mapping for stuff like 鵝叫聲，汽車喇叭聲, кряскам, भौंपू बजाना, 按喇叭, לִצפּוֹר, or κραυγή αγριόχηνας, κορνάρ?).

Comment: I agree that it's good to be aware of that. If it's desirable depends entirely on the locale and whether the locale matters. In German phone books, we have Ö at the end of the O section, I think in sweden they have separate sections for the umlauts at the end of the alphabet.

Comment: @omz, I'm creating a German app, and indeed there will be the Ö and Ä :)

Comment: If you want to convert Ö to O etc., you may want to have a look at `CFStringTransform`, specifically `kCFStringTransformStripDiacritics`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want through the following steps:

1. Create an empty but mutable dictionary.
2. Get the first character.
3. If a key for that character does not exist, create it.
4. Add the word to the value of the key (should be an NSMutableArray).
5. Repeat step #2 for all keys.

Here is the Objective-C code for these steps.  Note that I am assuming that you want the keys to be case **insensitive**.

```
// create our dummy dataset
NSArray * wordArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple", 
                       @"Pickle", @"Monkey", @"Taco", 
                       @"arsenal", @"punch", @"twitch", 
                       @"mushy", nil];
// setup a dictionary
NSMutableDictionary * wordDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString * word in wordArray) {
    // remove uppercaseString if you wish to keys case sensitive.
    NSString * letter = [[word substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] uppercaseString];
    NSMutableArray * array = [wordDictionary objectForKey:letter];
    if (!array) {
        // the key doesn't exist, so we will create it.
        [wordDictionary setObject:(array = [NSMutableArray array]) forKey:letter];
    }
    [array addObject:word];
}
NSLog(@"Word dictionary: %@", wordDictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this topic, they solves almost the same problem as you — [filtering NSArray into a new NSArray in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110332/filtering-nsarray-into-a-new-nsarray-in-objective-c) Let me know if it does not help so I will write for you one more code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to sort the contents of array in alphabetical order, further you design to the requirement

[keywordListArr sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote this sample. It looks simple and does what you need.

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Anna", @"Antony", @"Jack", @"John", @"Nikita", @"Mark", @"Matthew", nil];

NSString *alphabet = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";
NSMutableDictionary *sortedNames = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for(int characterIndex = 0; characterIndex < 25; characterIndex++) {
    NSString *alphabetCharacter = [alphabet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(characterIndex, 1)];
    NSArray *filteredNames = [names filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[C] %@", alphabetCharacter]];        
    [sortedNames setObject:filteredNames forKey:alphabetCharacter];
}

//Just for testing purposes let's take a look into our sorted data
for(NSString *key in sortedNames) {
    for(NSString *value in [sortedNames valueForKey:key]) {
        NSLog(@"%@:%@", key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work with UTF-8 and the use of a predict in that loop is going to be über-slow compared to omz's solution.