# Query Array In Objective C (Like MySQL)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, filter

So basically I have a huge array of arrays (only a 2-d array)...

My root array lets say has 100 child arrays...

I want to query the root/child arrays and return only the child arrays that have its 2 object equal to hello...

So basically I have a made-up idea below...

```
updatedArray = [rootArray WHERE childArray objectAtIndex:2 == @"hello"];
```

Now as you can see I want updated array to contain like 40 or 50 of the child arrays in the rootArray...

See what I mean - its kind of like MySQL  only with an array instead of a database?

Comment: btw this is unrelated to MySQL - it's a generic data structure question. And databases are also a data structure... :-)

Comment: I removed the MySQL and C tags, which are definitely unrelated.

Comment: @TheMan, read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/110332/274261). I would even say its a possible duplicate.

Comment: Btw, the second object is not at index 2! Obviously, it's at index one.

Comment: that's why I wrote "the 3rd object" in my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes your answer is correct (upvoted), the question isn't :)

Comment: thanks :) I thought OP was referring to the object at index 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *updated = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *a in rootArray)
{
    if ([[a objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"hello"])
        [updated addObject:a];
}
```

Now `updated` will contain the arrays in `rootArray` whose 3rd object is `@"hello"`.

Don't forget to release it after use (if you don't use ARC).

You can also use predicates for simple logic; see the [NSPredicate class.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795)

Comment: Surely a predicate would be better here?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your array using `NSPredicate`, like this:

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]
,   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Three", @"Four", nil]
,   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nine", @"Two", nil]
,   nil];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id array, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    // This is the place where the condition is specified.
    // You can perform arbitrary testing on your nested arrays
    // to determine their eligibility:
    return [[array objectAtIndex:1] isEqual:@"Two"];
}];
NSArray *res = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
NSLog(@"%lu", res.count);
```