# Objective C: What's the easiest way to determine if a substring exists within an NSString?

Tags: objective-c

In PHP (which is what I'm most familiar with) it's a one line expression:

```
strpos('abc', 'b') !== false
```

What's the Objective C equivalent?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C#Searching_for_a_Substring

Comment: The Cocoa classes are fairly well-documented. You're obviously encouraged to take a look at them any time you need something.

Comment: @zneak I totally agree but a simple question isn't necessarily a bad question - especially considering how contrived some people's solutions are to simple questions. Documenting good answers to simple questions is of benefit to the community. Proof in point (a post I made the other day): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439180/whats-the-easiest-way-to-remove-empty-nsstrings-from-an-nsarray Nobody should be writing code equal to some of the bad answers. Having the simple answer documented is ultimately a good thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[@"abc" rangeOfString:@"b"].location != NSNotFound
```

Answer (score 3):

I think categories can be use to package up pieces of functionality like this very nicely.

```
@interface NSString (ContainsString)
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)string;
@end

@implementation NSString (ContainsString)
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString:string options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    return range.location != NSNotFound;
}
@end
```

When used, it makes the meaning very clear.

```
if ([@"this is a string" containsString:@"a string"]) {
    …
}
```

In most projects this would be a part of a larger string method category and not it's own one-method category.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```

> Return Value An NSRange structure giving the location and length in
>   the receiver of the first occurrence of aString. Returns {NSNotFound,
>   0} if aString is not found or is empty (@"").

You can find more helpful string manipulation functions in the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)