# Filter the array that contains the specified string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, filter

I am trying to develop an app that contains an array with a huge number of words. I want to create a new filtered array from it. Filtering is done based on a pattern that I have managed to create using a regular expression. For example, I should be able to filter out the word "apple" with a pattern "ap_l_" from my array with words. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by that?  You need to provide a  little more information.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110332/filtering-nsarray-into-a-new-nsarray-in-objective-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below code it will filter the array

```
-(NSMutableArray *)searchByContains:(NSString *)containsString inputArray:(NSMutableArray *)inputArray
{
    NSLog(@"orginal Array count=%d",[inputArray count]);
    NSString *expression=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF contains '%@'",containsString];
    NSLog(@"expression=%@",expression);
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:expression];    
    NSMutableArray *mArrayFiltered = [[inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

    return mArrayFiltered;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to filter an array is to use predicates.  If you have an array of strings, for example:

```
NSArray *stringsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Joe", @"Bill", @"David", @"Jeff", nil];
```

you can easily filter it using filteredArrayUsingPredicate:.  If, for example, you wanted to filter the above array for all instances of @"Bill", you would do it like this:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [stringsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == 'Bill'"]];
```

if you want to filter OUT @"Bill", then you would do this:

```
filteredArray = [stringsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != 'Bill'"]];
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

if all element is string you can use .

```
for(NSString *str in arrayName)
  {
      if([str isEqualToString:@"searchString"])
         {

            //wirte own code here
         }



  }
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question... try this

```
if([your_array containsObject: your_string]){
      do something
}
```

hope this helps