# How to filter a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, filter, nsarray

Hey i want to filter an NSArray. In this Array is a lot of information like name, town, telephonenumber, and so on. But some towns are twice or three times in the array.
I have property with a town in it.
So i want only those objects from the arry which match with the property.

For example:
in the Array stands:

1. Frank, New York, 123456
2. Oliver, New York, 123456
3. Thomas, Boston, 123456

and when the property is New York i want olny objects 1 and 2.

Does anyone has an idea how i can do it?

This is my code:

```
NSString *filterString = newsArticle;
NSPredicate *prediacte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ort == '%@'",filterString]];
newsTownArray = [news filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and when i come to the line:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[[newsTownArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:"Name"];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [filtering NSArray into a new NSArray in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110332/filtering-nsarray-into-a-new-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [**NSPredicate**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) for this.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"town == 'New York'"];
[yourArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Dynamically you can create predicate like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"town == '%@'",yourInput]];
```

Here `yourInput` is a `NSString` which holds the required town name.

Please check these articles for more details:

1. [**codeproject**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68468/How-To-Do-Amazingly-Simple-Searches-With-NSArray-N)
2. [**useyourloaf**](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/19/searching-arrays-with-nspredicate-and-blocks.html)

Comment: but the town is not always the same. so is this also possible?

Comment: @theandrew: I'll add dynamic query, just wait

Comment: @theandrew: Please check now :)

Comment: Thank you a lot :)  But i also have to use the 2nd line from the first right?

Comment: @theandrew: yes you need to use that line also

Comment: i don't know why but it doesnt't work. i have all my objects in the array

Comment: @theandrew: there should be any issues with your predicate

Comment: The problem is the output. When i look at the content of the array it is ok. so I have only the objects with the right town. But i can't give it out.

Comment: @theandrew: means ? I didn't get you, can you explain a little bit

Comment: @theandrew: If that is the case then you need to reload the table and return the number of rows as the count of objects in `newsTownArray` array

Comment: there is a delegate method called the `numberOfRowInSection` `return [newsTownArray count];`

Comment: And you think that this is the failure?

Comment: @theandrew: I think now you are returning some other values from there. Check that.

Answer (score 0):

However you can do it within an array with the use of **NSPredicate**, but I will suggest to do bit differently, this will add up to your code and good programming way.

Create a custom class `Person` having these properties `name`, `city` and `telephone`.

Create an array that will store objects of `Person`.

After this you can manipulate/ filter / sort etc quite easily.

---

```
NSString *filterCity=@"Delhi";

NSMutableArray *yourArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.persons];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"city == '%@'",filterCity]];
[yourArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"Filtered");
for (Person *per in yourArray) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@, City: %@, Telephone: %@",per.name, per.city, per.telephone);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSString *term in arryOfWordsToBeSearched) {
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@",term];
        [subpredicates addObject:p];
        }

     NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
    result = (NSMutableArray*)[arryOfDummyData filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filter];
```