# How to find matching dictionaries within an NSArray based on strings contained from a different array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSArray full of dictionaries.

I want to loop through it and find all dictionaries that have an key value matching any of the string object that exists within a separate array.

I then want to add this to a new results array of all objects found.

This is how I do it now, but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient and faster way of doing this.

```
NSArray *arrayOfDictionaries, *arrayOfIDs;

NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayOfDictionaries) {

    for (NSString *userID in arrayOfIDs) {

        if ([userID isEqualToString:dict[@"user_id"]]) {

            [results addObject:dict];

        }
    }
}

return results;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code could be a bit simpler, by using the `NSArray containsObject:` method:

```
NSArray *arrayOfDictionaries, *arrayOfIDs;

NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayOfDictionaries) {

    if ([arrayOfIDs containsObject:dict[@"user_id"]) {

        [results addObject:dict];

    }
}

return results;
```

Note that although this code is nicer to read and understand, it still will have a similar [run-time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) to your original approach.

This is because although the code you posted has explicit `N^2` run-time complexity in the middle (a nested for loop), and my new version has apparently only `N` complexity, the `containsObject:` call contains a loop, so there's still `N^2` complexity.

If you wanted your algorithm to be more efficient -- **and only if this matters, don't prematurely optimise!** -- you could use an `NSSet` instead of an `NSArray` for storing the `usersIDs`. This would be faster because `NSArray` lookup is linear time, whereas `NSSet` uses hashing for lookups and has better than linear runtime lookups.

Note that if you want to put your own custom objects into an `NSSet`, you should override `isEquals:` and `hashcode` on that object. For more info, see [Best practices for overriding isEqual: and hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash)

Answer (score 1):

You can go even further and filter your initial `NSArray` and get a Set of Indexes.

```
NSIndexSet *results = [NSIndexSet indexSet];    

results = [arrayOfDictionaries indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [arrayOfIDs containsObject:obj[@"user_id"]];
}];
```

Note that your `containsObject` could be improved if you use an `NSSet` for your `arrayOfIDs` instead of an `NSArray`.

If you want more options to filter the array check this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110332/filtering-nsarray-into-a-new-nsarray-in-objective-c).