# How to get dates from array of dates?

Tags: ios, arrays, date, nsdateformatter

I have an array which contains different dates

```
    NSLog(@"Array of dates contains %@", [_dates valueForKey:@"date"]);
Array of dates contains (
    "2015-03-22 08:45:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-22 19:00:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-23 12:15:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-23 13:30:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-24 07:30:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-24 13:30:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-25 08:45:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-25 09:00:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-25 09:30:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-26 08:00:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-26 10:00:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-27 09:00:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-27 19:00:00 +0000",
    "2015-03-28 08:45:00 +0000"
)
```

I want to get from this array another array, which contains just (`2015-03-22, 2015-03-23, 2015-03-24`)
Please help me solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [filtering NSArray into a new NSArray in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110332/filtering-nsarray-into-a-new-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Comment: I take it you're looking for a new array of dates, though this time only containing the date (without the time info)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you simply want a new array with the date part only (removing the time info), you can do the following

```
NSArray *originalArray = [_dates valueForKey:@"date"];

//Create an empty mutableArray to add the new formatted date strings into
NSMutableArray *anotherArray = [NSMutableArray alloc];

//Choosing the format of the date you require from the NSDate object
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

    for (NSDate *date in originalArray) {

     //This line will make a string from the date which you specified to only use the yyyy-MM-dd etc.
     NSString *datesWithoutTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    [anotherArray addObject:datesWithoutTimeString];
    }
```

Now you will be left with a new MutableArray - `anotherArray` containing strings of the dates in the format you require.

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Cheers

Jim