# Filter JSON items in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, items

I have a little problem, I have a json feed and I would like to display in an array that items whose Country = France How to do ? Thank you 
(Objective-C) 
My JSON :

```
    { 
  "menu": "Fichier", 
  "commandes": [ 
      {
          "country": "France", 
          "city": "Paris"
      }, 
      {
          "country": "USA", 
          "city": "New York"
      }, 
      {
          "country": "Canada",
          "city": "Quebec"
      }
   ] 
}
```

Comment: Please check this link and I hope it helps [Filtering the NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110332/filtering-nsarray-into-a-new-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `NSPredicate` to search data from array

use below code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country == %@", @"France"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [[arr objectForKey:@"commandes"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Is it possible to get array while I pass "Fra" and get a "France" object?

Comment: No, This predicate will not work for this kind of query. You need to look for contain kind of predicate.

Answer (score 1):

First parse your JSON data using NSJSONSerialization

```
// data will be your Json NSData

 NSError* jsonError;
 NSDictionary* jsonDictn = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                             options:kNilOptions
                             error:&error];
 NSMutableArray * aray = [[jsonDictn objectForKey:@"commandes"] mutableCopy];
 for (NSDictionary* tmpdictn in aray) {
     NSString * tmpstr = [tmpdictn objectForKey:@"country"];
     if (![tmpstr isEqualToString:@"France"]) {
         [aray removeObject:tmpdictn];
      }
 }
 NSLog(@"aray: %@",aray);
```

Comment: If you have already created Array and just want to add filter that use NSPredicate, this code is to get only France Array from actual Json.

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"commandes" ascending:TRUE];
[sourceArr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];
```